# How to correctly link opencl with ros?

Tags: linux, cmake, opencl, ros

I just have installed opencl in my ubuntu 18 based on [this](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/1d13c7f432ba03a8e38720c83cd973d5) tutorial. i also find similar question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/12082/using-opencl-in-ros/) but i didn't understand it properly. Here are the folders inside the workspace:
[image] 
well i tried like below, but here only opencl_headers are not creating any error.

```
 include_directories(~/intel-compute-runtime/workspace/opencl_headers/CL)

 target_link_libraries(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me for opencl 2.1.

```
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /usr/include/CL/
)
add_executable(save_pattern src/save_pattern.cpp)
target_link_libraries(save_pattern ${catkin_LIBRARIES} /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so)
```

Installed it using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850281/opencl-on-ubuntu-16-04-intel-sandy-bridge-cpu/850594) ans.